# Store UInt64 in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to implement a "restore upload to dropbox" function when my app comes out of the background. To do this I need to save a *UInt64* that is given to my by the dropbox method:

```
func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, uploadFileChunkProgress progress: CGFloat, forFile uploadId: String!, offset: UInt64, fromPath localPath: String!)
```

I cannot save the offset value with the following:

```
defaults.setObject(offset, forKey: "uploadedOffset")
```

I can save the number if I convert it first to a *unsignedlonglong* but I can't cast it back to a *UInt64*

Is there a way to save a UInt64 into NSUserDefaults or do I need to use core data?

Comment: Wrap the `UInt64` in an `NSNumber` as store the `NSNumber` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: When I try that I have to convert it to an unsigned long long:    _let numberOffset = NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: offset)_  How do I cast it back to UInt64 when I retrieve it later?

Comment: @lernerbot and what's wrong with that? an `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits long.

Comment: The dropbox method that I need to call after retrieval requires a UInt64

Comment: @lernerbot Use the `unsignedLongLongValue` method of `NSNumber` to get back the `UInt64` value.